# When does VBA change variable type without being asked to?

Tags: vba, excel

I am getting a runtime error I don't understand in Excel 2011 for Mac under OS X 10.7.5.  Here is a summary of the code:

```
Dim h, n, k as Integer
Dim report as Workbook
Dim r1 as Worksheet
Dim t, newline as String
Dim line() as String

newline = vbCr
'
' (code to get user input from a text box, to select a worksheet by number)
'
ReDim line(report.Sheets.Count + 10)
MsgBox "Array line has " & UBound(line) & " elements."   '----> 21 elements
line = split(t, newline)
h = UBound(line)
MsgBox "Array line has " & h & " elements."              '----> 16 elements
n = 0
MsgBox TypeName(n)              '----> Integer
For k = h To 1 Step -1
    If IsNumeric(line(k)) Then
        n = line(k)
        Exit For
    End If
Next k
If n > 0 Then
    MsgBox n                    '----> 7
    MsgBox TypeName(n)          '----> String
    Set r1 = report.Sheets(n)   '----> Runtime error "Subscript out of bounds"
```

So n is declared as an integer, but now VBA thinks it is a string and looks for a worksheet named "7".  Is this a platform bug, or is there something I haven't learned yet?

It also surprises me that putting data into the dynamic array reduces its dimension, but perhaps that is normal, or perhaps for dynamic arrays Ubound returns the last used element instead of the dimension, although I have not seen that documented.

Comment: No n is declared as a variant.  to declare as integer the line must be: `Dim h as Integer, n as Integer, k as Integer`

Comment: also if t is be a string then `Dim t as string, newline as String`

Comment: As to the array when you use `line = split(t, newline)` it re initializes the array.  It literally throws out the old array and fills a new one.  If it had data the data would be over written.  You do not need the ReDim line at all.

Answer (score 3):

The first part of your question is answered by @ScottCraner in the comments -  the correct syntax for declaring multiple strongly typed variables on one line is:

```
Dim h As Integer, n As Integer, k As Integer
'...
Dim t As String, newline As String
```

So, I'll address the second part of your question specific to `UBound` - unless you've declared `Option Base 1` at the top of the module, your arrays start at element 0 by default, not element 1. However, the `Split` function ***always*** returns a 0 based array (unless you split a `vbNullString`, in which case you get a `LBound` of -1):

```
Private Sub ArrayBounds()
    Dim foo() As String

    'Always returns 3, regardless of Option Base:
    foo = Split("zero,one,two,three", ",")
    MsgBox UBound(foo)

    ReDim foo(4)
    'Option Base 1 returns 1,4
    'Option Base 0 (default) returns 0,3
    MsgBox LBound(foo) & "," & UBound(foo)
End Sub
```

That means this line is extremely misleading...

```
h = UBound(line)
MsgBox "Array line has " & h & " elements."
```

...because the Array line actually has ***h + 1*** elements, which means that your loop here...

```
For k = h To 1 Step -1
    If IsNumeric(line(k)) Then
        n = line(k)
        Exit For
    End If
Next k
```

...is actually ***skipping element 0***. You don't really even need the `h` variable at all - you can just make your loop parameter this...

```
For k = UBound(line) To LBound(line) Step -1
    If IsNumeric(line(k)) Then
        n = line(k)
        Exit For
    End If
Next k
```

...and not have to worry ***what*** the base of the array is.

BTW, not asked, but storing `vbCr` as a variable here...

```
newline = vbCr
```

...isn't necessary at all, and opens the door for all kinds of other problems if you intend that a "newline" is always `vbCr`.  Just use the pre-defined constant `vbCr` directly.

Comment: To go one step further, **vbLf** (aka `Chr(10)`) is a *linefeed* and a **vbCrlF** (aka `Chr(13) & Chr(10)`) is a new 'paragraph'. I don't know what the OP means by 'newline' but **vbCr** is a *carriage-return* or  single `Chr(13)` and is generally not used in polite company.

Comment: @Jeeped - Not a Mac user, but I'm guessing it uses Unix style line endings - i.e. bare carriage-return without a line-feed.

Comment: Good point - I wasn't thinking xNIX/MAC specifics and I should have been. [Difference between Carriage Return, Line Feed and End of Line Characters.](http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/5A5A050A3019A573862575F30061D49B)

Comment: `the Split function always returns a 0 based array`  
Similarly, if you populate an implicitly declared array from a worksheet range, it's always 1-based.

Comment: Thank you all for the prompt solutions, explanations, and suggestions.  Yes, I have found that "newline" needs to be vbCR on the Mac and vbLf when the same code runs on a PC.  That's why it's a variable.

Comment: @cat22 - If it needs to run cross-platform, you can use a pre-compiler check for `Mac`: `#If Mac Then` `Const LineEnding = vbCr` `#Else` `Const LineEnding = vbCrLf` `#End If`

Comment: Comintem, thank you for the suggestion but I would like to make a spreadsheet that can just open and run on either platform, without requiring the user to know how to compile it first.  Can the #If system do that?

Comment: @cat22 - Yes, it will automagically use the correct `LineEnding` based on which platform it's running on.

Comment: The Microsoft documentation seems to indicate that multiple variables can be declared on one line as I have been doing:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ee5a7s1.aspx

"Dim lastTime, nextTime, allTimes() As Date"

Comment: @cat22 - They can, but they will default to `Variant` unless you specify a type for each individual variable.  A `Variant` can hold *anything*, so you can put either a `String` or an `Integer` in one.  If you *require* a variable to be one or the other, you need to explicitly declare it with a type.

Comment: The web page I cited seems to contradict that.  But of course the manual is not always correct.

Comment: @cat22 - The linked page is VB.NET, not VBA.